# Old calendar reminders continue to pop up on my iPhone 6

Tags: ios, reminders

I have a fully updated iPhone 6. I continue to get old calendar reminders showing up on my iPhone. It routinely reminds me of a regular meeting that has been cancelled for two years in some cases.

**I have gone into the Reminders app, but nothing shows there.** None of these old meetings are on my calendar anymore.

How do I get rid of the old reminders?

Re:  The suspected dupe - As noted above, I have gone through the Reminders app. There is nothing there. The previous questions about reminders do not help me as they are not relevant.